# Free objects in $\mathrm{Set}(G).$

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, group-actions

What are the free objects in the category of $G$-sets for a group $G$?

After considerable deliberation (I'm not very bright), I'm pretty sure they are the $G$-sets $X$ on which $G$ acts freely, that is in such a way that only $e$ fixes any elements in $X$. I can prove it -- almost.

Suppose $X$ is a $G$-set on which $G$ acts freely. Let's take a transversal $B$ of the set of orbits $X/G$. I will show that $X$ is a free object in the category of $G$-sets, and $B$ is its basis. Let $Y$ be an arbitrary $G$-set, and let $f:B\to Y$ be any function. Suppose $\tilde f:X\to Y$ is a $G$-set morphism extending $f$. Let $x\in X$. Then there exist $b\in B$ and $g\in G$ such that $gb=x.$ Then $$\tilde f(x)=\tilde f(gb)=g\tilde f(b)=gf(b).$$
Hence the extension $\tilde f$ is unique.

For the existence of $\tilde f$, it's enough to check that the above is a good definition, or that it doesn't depend on the choice of $g$. Suppose $gb=x$ and $g'b=x$. Then $b=g^{-1}g'b$, and since $G$ acts freely on $X$, we must have $g=g'.$ Therefore the extension $\tilde f$ exists and is unique, and so $X$ is a free object in the category of $G$-sets.

Now suppose $X$ is a free object in the category of $G$-sets. Suppose for a moment that the following lemma is true.

*Lemma.* If $X$ is a free object in the category of $G$-sets, then its bases are exactly the transversals of $X/G.$

With this lemma I can show that $G$ must act freely on $X$. For let $x\in X.$ Then there exist a (unique, but I don't think I need this) $b\in B$ and $g\in G$ such that $gb=x.$ Suppose for an $h\in G$ we have $hx=x.$ This means that $$g^{-1}hgb=b.$$ Now let $f:B\to G$ be any function. Since $B$ is a basis, we can extend it uniquely to a $G$-set morphism $\tilde f$. ($G$ acts on itself by multiplication.) This implies that $$g^{-1}hgf(b)=f(b).$$ But $f(b)$ can be chosen arbitrarily, which means that $g^{-1}hg$ must fix every element of $G$, and so $h=e.$

So what I need to do is prove the lemma. Actually, I just need the "exactly" part. I just need to know that if $X$ is a free object in the category $G$-sets, then its basis must be a transversal of $X/G.$

Suppose $X$ is a free object. A transversal is a subset of $X$ such that there is exactly one element of each orbit in it. I think the uniqueness is analogous to linear independence in a vector space, and the existence is analogous to spanning the whole space. I can show the uniqueness (but as I said, I don't think I need it actually). Suppose $B$ is a basis of $X$. Suppose there are $b,b'\in B$ such that $b'=gb$ for some $g$. Again, by considering the functions $f:B\to G$, I can show that $g=e.$

But I don't see how to show that every orbit must have a representative in $B$. (Please keep in mind that at this point I still haven't proven that $G$ acts freely on $X$.) Since this is analogous to the fact that a vector space basis must generate the whole space, I've looked at the proof of that, the one in which we generate a subspace by the basis, quotient it out and show that the quotient is $0$. Can it be done here? I don't know how to define a quotient of a $G$-set. Or maybe I just need to prove it in some other way?

Comment: Linguistic note: "free object in $C$" takes as input not a category $C$ but a *concrete* category, namely a category $C$ together with a choice of forgetful functor $C \to \text{Set}$. The notion of freeness depends on this choice.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. Is there another forgetful functor here (other than the obvious one) that gives different free objects?

Comment: many! Given any object $c \in C$ you get a functor $\text{Hom}(c, -) : C \to \text{Set}$, and the corresponding free objects are the coproducts of $c$ if $C$ has all coproducts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I've only read the first line of your question.

If $X$ is a set, the free $G$-set on $X$ is $G \times X$ with the $G$-action $g(h,x)=(gh,x)$. This is because for every $G$-set $Y$ every map $\alpha : X \to Y$ of sets extends uniquely to a $G$-map $G \times X \to Y$ via $(g,x) \mapsto g\, \alpha(x)$.

A $G$-set is free in the sense of category theory iff it is free in the usual sense: $\Rightarrow$ follows since $G$ acts freely on $G \times X$. For $\Leftarrow$ assume that $G$ acts freely on a set $X$. Let $B$ be a system of representatives of $G/X$. Then $B \hookrightarrow X$ extends to a $G$-map $G \times B \to X$, which is surjective by construction. It is also injective: If $gb=g'b'$, then $b=b'$ (by definition of $B$), and then $g=g'$ (since the action is free).

Good that you asked this, I didn't know  this up to now!

(More generally, if $T : C \to C$ is a monad in a category, we can consider the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Mod}(T) \to C$, and it's left adjoint is given by $x \mapsto (T(x),\mu_x)$. For example, when $G$ is a monoid object in $C$ and $C$ has products, then $T(X) = G \times X$ is a monad and $\mathsf{Mod}(T)=\mathsf{Mod}(G)$ is the category of objects of $C$ together with a left $G$-action, for short $G$-objects. The free $G$-object on an object $X \in C$ is therefore $G \times X$ with the obvious $G$-action.)

Comment: Thanks. The $G\times X$ interpretation seems very useful, and it does seem to solve my problem. The proof of the implication I was having trouble with is very simple here. I will need to think about this because I still need to understand how it's done without the interpretation, which is what I was trying to do in the question.

Comment: You want to show $\Rightarrow$ only using the universal property, instead of the concrete description of free objects? I don't think that this is possible. And even if it works, it will be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I don't understand why it should be impossible. It can be done for vector spaces. As I say in the question, all I need is that when I have a basis (understood in terms of the universal property), then it has to generate the whole $G$-set. (Or, in other words, the union of their orbits is the whole $G$-set.) This is easy to do for a vector space $V$. We generate a space $V'$ by the basis, and take the quotient $V/V'$. It turns out it has to be $0$, and so $V=V'$.

Comment: OK, I think I know how to do it. I'll post an answer. Please take a look whether it's OK, if you find the time.

Comment: I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I want to show that if a $G$-set $X$ is a free object in the category of $G$-sets, then its basis $B$ has to generate $X$. In other words,

$$\langle B\rangle=\bigcup_{b\in B}\mathrm{orb}(b)=X.$$

Let's say that an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ is a congruence whenever for any $x,x'\in X$ and $g\in G$ we have $$a\sim x'\implies gx\sim gx'.$$

It's easy to show that the usual things hold: the kernel of a $G$-morphism is a congruence relation; quotient $G$-sets are well-defined; the first isomorphism theorem holds.

Now let $X$ be free with basis $B$. It's clear that the relation $\sim$ on $X$ defined by $$x\sim x'\iff(x=x'\vee x,x'\in\langle B\rangle)$$

is a congruence on $X$. It's a relation that contracts $\langle B\rangle$ to a single element and doesn't touch the rest of the elements. Let's denote that single element by $0$. Let $\tilde f:X\to X/\sim$ be the canonical $G$-epimorphism.  Now clearly for any $b\in B$, we have $\tilde f(b)=0.$ But the function $\tilde f':X\to X/\sim$ assigning $0$ to every element of $X$ is also a $G$-morphism. $\tilde f$ and $\tilde f'$ are equal when restricted to $B$, and therefore must be equal, since $B$ is a basis. Hence for any $x,x'\in X$ we must have $x\sim x'$ and so every element of $X$ belongs to $\langle B\rangle.$

Comment: This is a general fact from universal algebra. If $F$ is a free algebraic object on some set $B$, then $F$ is generated by (the image of) $B$. The reason is simply that $\langle B \rangle \to F$ induces bijections on hom-sets, therefore is an isomorphism by Yoneda. Remark that this observation does not suffice for $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thank you for the comment. Yes, of course it doesn't suffice. The rest of the proof is in the question.